# How to routing from a page inside <router-outlet> to another inside <router-outlet> in AngularDart

Tags: dart, routes, angular-dart, angular-dart-routing

In my `app_component.html` file I have a `navbar` and, below of it:

```
<router-outlet [routes]="Routes.all"></router-outlet>
```

In my `Routes.all` I have 2 pages: `page1` and `page2`. In my `page1` page I have a button. When the user clicks on it, the `page2` would be shown. How can I do this?

I tried –without results– this in way (in my page1.html file):

```
<material-fab raised>
    <a [routerLink]="RoutePaths.page2.toUrl()" [routerLinkActive]="'active'">
        <img src="img/icons/outline-photo_camera-24px.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
</a>
</material-fab>
```